# Confusion on cvSplit function

Tags: opencv

what is the proper way of using `cvSplit` function? I saw different version of it.
should it be

```
cvSplit(oriImg, r,g,b, NULL);
```

or

```
cvSplit(oriImg, b,g,r, NULL);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of them are ok, it depends on the channel ordering. By default OpenCV uses BGR, so in this case it would be `cvSplit(oriImg, b,g,r, NULL);`, but you can convert it to RGB and then use the other one.

Comment: Hi Bob, that's what I thought too. OpenCV uses BGR by default. I saw some post uses RGB sequence and make me think twice which is correct. Thanks;)

Answer (score 0):

It is exactly the same thing I was puzzled by when I started using OpenCV. OpenCV uses BGR instead of RGB so you should use

cvSplit(img,b,g,r,NULL);